# Responsive navigation links being pushed under navigation bar when browser is made smaller

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a responsive website. I had a navigation bar on top of the page with links on the right and social media icons on the left. When I make the browser smaller it pushes the links under the navigation bar as if it was being pushed into another div.

I believe the social icons are causing the problem. They are two different div's inside multiple div's. If I remove the social icons it works but I would like to keep the social icons top left.

```
<body>
<div id="outerWrapper"> </div>
<div id="navWrapper">
<div id="navInnerWrapper">
    <div id="topSocials">
        <a href="URL"><img alt="facebook icon" src="images/fb_social.png"></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="URL"><img  alt="linkedin icon" src="images/linkedin_social.png"></a>
        </div>
    <div id="navBar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
#outerWrapper {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: block;
position: relative;
color: #333333;
font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu 
Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
text-align: left;
line-height: 20px;
}
#navWrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 45px;
display: block;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
position: relative;
clear: both;
border-bottom: 3px solid #000000;
background-color: #9FA2B2;
}
#navInnerWrapper {
width: auto;
height: auto;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
position: relative;
clear: both;
padding-right: 200px;
}
#topSocials {
width: 231px;
display: block;
position: relative;
float: left;
height: auto;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-left: 50px;
}
#navBar {
width: 600px;
display: block;
position: relative;
float: right;
height: auto;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: right;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
}
ul li {
display: inline;
padding-left: 40px;
}

#navBar a:link {color: #16262E; text-decoration: none; }
#navBar a:visited {color: #16262E; text-decoration: none; }
#navBar a:hover {color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none; }
#navBar a:active {color: #16262E; text-decoration: none; }
```

This is what it looks like when I make the browser smaller.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8egL.jpg

Want the navigation to be responsive with links on the right and social icons on the left.

Answer (score 0):

You have a very bad code. See how many properties I fixed and added to you in CSS. Learn better.

```css
#navWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 45px; */
  /* display: block; */
  /* padding-top: 10px; */
  /* padding-bottom: 10px; */
  /* position: relative; */
  /* clear: both; */
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000000;
  background-color: #9FA2B2;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#navInnerWrapper {
  /* width: auto; */
  /* height: auto; */
  /* display: block; */
  /* margin-left: auto; */
  /* margin-right: auto; */
  /* position: relative; */
  /* clear: both; */
  /* padding-right: 200px; */
  /* padding: 20px 0; */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#topSocials {
  /* width: 231px; */
  /* display: block; */
  /* position: relative; */
  /* float: left; */
  /* height: auto; */
  /* padding-top: 5px; */
  /* padding-left: 50px; */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 10px;
}

#topSocials a {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#navBar {
  /* width: 600px; */
  /* display: block; */
  /* position: relative; */
  /* float: right; */
  /* height: auto; */
  /* color: #FFFFFF; */
  /* text-align: right; */
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  /* display: inline; */
  /* padding-left: 40px; */
  margin-left: 20px;
}

ul li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

#navBar a:link {
  color: #16262E;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navBar a:visited {
  color: #16262E;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navBar a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navBar a:active {
  color: #16262E;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="navWrapper">
  <div id="navInnerWrapper">
    <div id="topSocials">
      <a href="URL"><img alt="facebook icon" src="images/fb_social.png"></a>
      <a href="URL"><img alt="linkedin icon" src="images/linkedin_social.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="navBar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The code is from a responsive contest website done as a project for a CSS class. I am trying to use the code to practice building my own responsive website but not for the same purpose so I had to add and remove a bunch of stuff. Your code works well but the social icons are on two different rows. Going to try to fix it myself, thank you for the help.

Comment: @John Thomas social icons fixed now.